# sails.js join tables on mongodb native id

Tags: mongodb, sails.js, waterline, sails-mongo

I have two collections in mongodb database and  model for each of them

App Model

```
module.exports = {

    tableName: 'app',
    attributes: {
        _id : {
            primaryKey: true,
            unique: true,
            type: 'string',
        },
        userId: {
            model: 'user'
        },
        title: {
            type: 'string',
            required: true,
            unique: true,
        },
        createdDate : 'string'
    },
};
```

and User Model

```
module.exports = {

    tableName: 'user',
    attributes: {
        id : {
            primaryKey: true,
            unique: true,
            type: 'string',
            collection: "app",
            via : "userId"
        },
        password: {
            type: 'string',
            required: true
        },
        apps : {
            collection: "app",
            via : "userId"
        }
    },

};
```

When i use numeric values for join this collection, it works fine, but when i try do it with mongodb native id object, i get the empty result

How i call join query

```
User.find().populate('apps').exec(function(err, result) {});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get rid of both the `_id` and `id` attribute definitions in your models.  Waterline will handle the primary key fields for you automatically (normalizing them to `id`), so unless you need to change the field type, they can be safely left out.  Also, I'm not sure what your intention was by adding `collection` and `via` to the `id` definition, but the primary key is never going to be an association.

Otherwise, your models look correct.  If you get rid of those two attributes, things should work fine.